# Is there any way to use a USB flash memory drive as computer RAM?

Tags: windows-7, memory, windows-vista, usb-flash-drive

Someone told me that he can improve the computer speed by increasing the size of RAM using a USB flash memory drive. I just want to know how that might be possible.

Answer (score 3):

No. Its not possible to use a USB pen drive as RAM.

What you can do though is use a USB drive to cache some data from the hard disk that will be heading to RAM. For some operations the USB stick will be faster than a spinning hard disk, especially on systems that are memory starved (less than 1gb of RAM on Windows 7) but on systems with plenty of RAM the speed boost will be negligible.

The technology is known as [Readyboost](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/turn-readyboost-on-off-storage-device#1TC=windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

You wanna specific info? well here:
http://lifehacker.com/5573801/turn-a-usb-flash-drive-into-extra-virtual-ram
But in the comments I heard this method is going to kill the usb stick. It is the same as the one that you create in the harddrive (i.e. pagefile).
And some info about readyboost is here to help you: [HTG Explains: Is ReadyBoost Worth Using?](http://www.howtogeek.com/123780/htg-explains-is-readyboost-worth-using/)
You know, I suggest you its best to buy another RAM. These tricks does not have such a big impact at all.

Comment: This answer would be helpful if it contained the relevant information in the answer itself.

Answer (score 0):

No and you would not want to, for the USB Flash Memory Drive is several orders of magnitude slower at accessing its contents than internal RAM. It has to move its data through the USB interface which slows things down significantly when compared to memory access speed.